# Can't find wand/MagickWand.h

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, imagemagick, rmagick

I have update my system to Ubuntu 15.04 and now Rmagick can't be installed...

It gives me the following error:

```
$ gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/maria/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150428-16155-3f5duq.rb extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I install all the packages needed (imagemagick libmagickwand-dev, etc, I have tried all the packages described in other questions)

Does someone had the same problem? Any clue?

Everything was working fine before updating to 15.04

EDIT
I managed to make it work purging imagemagick and installing from source http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php?ImageMagick=9s6tlikqbn5eb0u0spg5o38sa4#unix

Now gives me this error: This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.9.1 but ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 is in use.

Comment: `apt-get install libmagickwand-6-headers`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! This package was already installed... :(

Comment: give gem version , using `gem -v`

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer! It gives me 2.4.6...

Comment: `gem update --system 2.4.6` And try to install gem

Comment: Thanks jon... it says Latest version currently installed. Aborting.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I fixed it up updating rmagick. What I did was:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
bundle update rmagick
```

And now bundle works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I am on ubuntu 15.04 and was able to get it by specifying version of rmagick

```
gem 'rmagick', '2.15.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on **Debian/Ubuntu** I was able to fix it by doing the following:

1. `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`
2. `sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat`
3. `PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH" gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'`

your lib versions may be different so check the version in `/usr/lib/x86...`

I got this from this discussion: https://github.com/ttscoff/Slogger/issues/344

Comment: The package `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` was needed for me

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem on clean Ubuntu 15.4 installation. Upgrade `rmagick` from `2.13.2` to `2.15.0` helped.

Things I tried, that did not help:

- manually symlink in `/usr/include/wand` `MagickWand.h` ⇒ `magick_wand.h`;
- rolling back to `libmagickcore-dev`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi,at the end, the only thing that worked was to install the same version of ImageMagick from source. Thanks

Comment: Installing it from source worked for me too :) thanks.
Ref: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php