# ImageMagick / Can't find wand/MagickWand.h / Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, imagemagick, rmagick

I was trying to install RMagick 2.13.4 for a few hours, and could't do it.

I find a post that has de same problem, but was no't resolved: [Can't find wand/MagickWand.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914304/cant-find-wand-magickwand-h)

This is my console log:

```
Installing rmagick 2.13.4 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/gfioriello/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151013-8735-126suhh.rb extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.4. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/gfioriello/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/gfioriello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@self_service/gems/rmagick-2.13.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/gfioriello/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@self_service/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0/rmagick-2.13.4/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I has Ubuntu 15.04

I install all the packages needed (imagemagick libmagickwand-dev, etc, I have tried all the packages described in other questions)

And this is my version of ImageMagick

```
gfioriello@dvt-005:~$ identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2015-01-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

If somebody knows what to do, it will be appreciate.

Comment: have you tried to switch to ruby from ubuntu repository?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-6-headers libmagickwand-dev libmagickwand-6.q16-dev`

Comment: yes, there is all installed.. I try to do: `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'` but got this: `Can't install RMagick 2.13.4. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***`

Comment: I've got this same problem: i have all the packages listed, but still get that exact same error as you.  Did you ever fix it?  If so can you remember what you did?  thanks

Answer (score -1):

1. first check rmagick version supports which imagemagick and download according to it through this link **https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/releases/**
2. second once you download unzip it and go to the folder and open terminal and type command in terminal step by step **a)./configure b) make c) sudo make install and for uninstall same version sudo make uninstall follow this link for the further information https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php d) sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib**
   **e) sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
   f) sudo apt-get install  libmagickcore-dev g) sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat**
3. once everything is done type **convert --version** to check the version and proper installation.
   The output will be like **Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
   Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
   License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
   Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
   Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib**.
4. if **nothing is working than you have installed wrong ImageMagick version go to second point and uninstall it step by step** a)**./configure** b) **make** c)**sudo make uninstall**. It is just same proces as installing for Imagemagick instead you have to use sudo make uninstall.